# Multiple Separators for the same file input R

Tags: r, csv, import, delimiter, separator

I've had a look for answers, but have only found things referring to C or C#. 
I realise that much of R is written in C but my knowledge of it is non-existent.
I am also relatively new to R.
I am using the current Rstudio.

This is similar to what I want, I think.
[Read the data efficiently with multiple separating lines in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606321/read-the-data-efficiently-with-multiple-separating-lines-in-r)

I have a csv file but one variable is a string with values separated by `_` and `-`
And I would like to know if there is a package or extra code which does the following on the read. command.

```
"1","Client1","Name2","*Name3_Name1_KB_MobApp_M-13-44_AU_PI Likes by KB_ANDROID","2013-08-31 13:39:55.0","2013-10-16 13:58:00.0",0,218,4,93,1377907200000
"2","Client1","Name2","*Name3_Name1_KB_MobApp_M-13-44_AU_PI Likes by KB_ANDROID","2013-08-31 13:39:55.0","2013-10-16 13:58:00.0",0,390,5,157,1377993600000
"3","Client1","Name2","*Name3_Name1_KB_MobApp_M-13-44_AU_PI Likes by KB_ANDROID","2013-08-31 13:39:55.0","2013-10-16 13:58:00.0",0,376,5,193,1.37808e+12
"4","Client1","Name2","*Name3_Name1_KB_MobApp_M-13-44_AU_PI Likes by KB_ANDROID","2013-08-31 13:39:55.0","2013-10-16 13:58:00.0",1,35,1,15,1377907200000
"5","Client1","Name2","*Name3_Name1_KB_MobApp_M-13-44_AU_PI Likes by KB_ANDROID","2013-08-31 13:39:55.0","2013-10-16 13:58:00.0",12,11258,117,2843,1377993600000
"6","Client1","Name2","*Name3_Name1_KB_MobApp_M-13-44_AU_PI Likes by KB_ANDROID","2013-08-31 13:39:55.0","2013-10-16 13:58:00.0",5,4659,56,1826,1.37808e+12
"7","Client1","Name2","*Name3_Name1_KB_MobApp_M-13-44_AU_PI Likes by KB_ANDROID","2013-08-31 13:39:55.0","2013-10-16 13:58:00.0",7,7296,136,2684,1377907200000
"8","Client1","Name2","*Name3_Name1_KB_MobApp_M-13-44_AU_PI Likes by KB_IOS_IPAD","2013-08-31 13:18:21.0","2013-10-16 13:58:00.0",0,4533,35,1632,1377907200000
"9","Client1","Name2","*Name3_Name1_KB_MobApp_M-13-44_AU_PI Likes by KB_IOS_IPAD","2013-08-31 13:18:21.0","2013-10-16 13:58:00.0",0,421,6,161,1377993600000
"10","Client1","Name2","*Name3_Name1_KB_MobApp_M-13-44_AU_PI Likes by KB_IOS_IPAD","2013-08-31 13:18:21.0","2013-10-16 13:58:00.0",0,57,2,23,1.37808e+12
```

Example row:

```
Name    Name1   *XYZ_Name3_KB_MobApp_M-18-25_AU_PI ANDROID  2013-09-32 14:39:55.0   2013-10-16 13:58:00.0   0   218 4   93  1377907200000
```

So it's easy enough to read in

```
results <- read.delim("~/results", header=F)
```

but then I still have the string *XYZ_Name3_KB_MobApp_M-18-25_AU_PI

Desired output(separate by `_` and by `-`):

```
Name    Name1   *XYZ   Name3  KB   MobApp   M 18 25  AU  PI ANDROID 2013-09-32 14:39:55.0   2013-10-16 13:58:00.0   0   218 4   93  1377907200000
```

but not split up the time string.

---- Thanks @Henrik and @AnandaMahto for the code and package. ----

```
library(splitstackshape)

# split concatenated column by `_`
df4 <- concat.split(data = df3, split.col = "V3", sep = "_", drop = TRUE)

# split the remaining concatenated part by `-`
df5 <- concat.split(data = df4, split.col = "V3_5", sep = "-", drop = TRUE)
```

Comment: I have the option of exporting again to csv and then putting into excel and using text to columns twice. but as I'm on excel 2010 it's with a limited # of rows.

Comment: Have a look at `str_split` or `stringr::str_split_fixed` and see if that helps.

Comment: Ah, so simple. Do you think I should do it it multiple steps then? Rather than on import.

Comment: I'd do it right after import. I'll post snippet below.

Comment: you can specify more than one split character in strsplit using regex and | operator, e.g strsplit("*XYZ_Name3_KB_MobApp_M-18-25_AU_PI ANDROID",split="\\_|\\-")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
# dummy data
df <- read.table(text="
Name    Name1   *XYZ_Name3_KB_MobApp_M-18-25_AU_PI ANDROID  2013-09-32 14:39:55.0   2013-10-16 13:58:00.0   0   218 4   93  1377907200000
Name    Name2   *CCC_Name3_KB_MobApp_M-18-25_AU_PI ANDROID  2013-09-32 14:39:55.0   2013-10-16 13:58:00.0   0   218 4   93  1377907200000
", as.is = TRUE)

# replace "_" to "-"
df_V3 <- gsub(pattern="_", replacement="-", df$V3, fixed = TRUE)

# strsplit, make dataframe
df_V3 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(df_V3, split = "-"))

# output, merge columns
output <- cbind(df[, c(1:2)],
                df_V3,
                df[, c(4:ncol(df))])
```

---

Building on the comments below, here is another related option, but one which uses `read.table` instead of `strsplit`.

```
splitCol <- "V3"
temp <- read.table(text = gsub("-", "_", df[, splitCol]), sep = "_")
names(temp) <- paste(splitCol, seq_along(temp), sep = "_")
cbind(df[setdiff(names(df), splitCol)], temp)
```

Comment: @zx8754, two ideas: (1) If you're going to use the `strsplit` approach, use a regular expression and skip the `gsub` step, and maybe just use `do.call(rbind, ...)` since (I *think*) `rbind.data.frame` is slower (and it gives you funky names). (2) If you're going to use the `gsub` approach, forget about `strsplit` and use `read.table(text = df_V3, sep = "-")`.

Comment: But +1 for an answer that should at least point the OP in the right direction ;-)

Comment: I would upvote if I had enough reputation points. But sadly not yet.

Comment: @ChristianArnold, Edit your question with some reproducible data and some examples of what you've tried, and people are sure to give you more up-votes on your question, which in turn will let you vote on answers ;-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto agree, code is *a bit* messy, intention was to direct the OP in the right direction, feel free to edit.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I've put in 10 lines of data, but will that help? Also, I retried with your package and it works good now! :)

Answer (score 5):

I find the functions in package `splitstackshape` convenient in cases like this.

```
library(splitstackshape)

# split concatenated column by `_`
results2 <- concat.split(data = results, split.col = "V3", sep = "_", drop = TRUE)

# split the remaining concatenated part by `-`
results3 <- concat.split(data = results2, split.col = "V3_5", sep = "-", drop = TRUE)
results3
```

Comment: I'm getting an "Error in FUN(NA_integer_[[1L]], ...) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer"   but thanks for the package I'll have look into making it work.

Comment: OK. Possibly there are some characteristics of your original data which are not represented in the small sample in your question (which works fine, for me). Cheers.

Comment: @ChristianArnold, as the package's author, I'd be interested in seeing some actual data that creates this error and the steps to reproduce it. Feel free to do so by [creating an issue at the package's Github issue tracker](https://github.com/mrdwab/splitstackshape/issues?state=open). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
library(stringr)

results <- read.delim("~/results", header=F)
results <- cbind(results,str_split_fixed(results$V3, "[_-]", 9))
```

(this assumes you're OK with having the original column still in place)